# When something is published in instalments, is there a word for that?

Tags: single-word-requests

If something is not published as a book, but is published in sections, or instalments, is there a word, other than 'instalments ?

All I can find online is the word 'serialised ', but we do  not call the individual items, *serials*.

Comment: It is *serialized* .

Comment: @HotLicks I prefer the 's' form as here --> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/serialise

Comment: The individual portions are *instalments*. The work is produced or published *instalmentally*. These are pretty darn precise matches to the situation. What problem do you see with them?

Comment: @PhilSweet I was hoping for a specific term.

Comment: The s/z thing is a US/UK difference.

Comment: @PhilSweet - the problem I see is that *instalmentally* is a hideous word.

Comment: @Jim I found _fascicle_ myself, but it was voted down for some  reason.

Comment: @NigelJ That isn't a reason for a down vote. Did you delete it? You should undelete it.

Comment: Serialized is (AmE spelling) the right word; the individual parts are called parts or, sometimes, chapters, or, as someone already said, installments.

Comment: -ize is always preferable as it is the traditional 20th century British English spelling as well as the US spelling. The pocket Oxford Dictionary I had in the 50s had only -ize spellings. The technical difference is in -yse v. -yze spellings (British English -yse, e.g. lyse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have suggested:

> A **partwork** is a written publication released as a series of planned magazine-like issues over a period of time. Issues are typically released on a weekly, fortnightly or monthly basis, and often a completed set is designed to form a reference work on a particular topic.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partwork#:~:text=A%20partwork%20is%20a%20written,work%20on%20a%20particular%20topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partwork#:%7E:text=A%20partwork%20is%20a%20written,work%20on%20a%20particular%20topic).

Answer (score 4):

The specific term depends on the medium.

Serialized novels are published in *chapters*, (as with 19th century novels), or *parts*, (several chapters of a novel spread out into a few issues of a specialized fiction magazine, *e.g.* "*Part I of IV*".).

[Serial films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_film) were presented weekly in *chapters*.

Serialized television narrative dramas are broadcast in *episodes*, grouped in *seasons* or *story arcs*.  Television dramas that are not long narratives, are called *episodic*, and if these are on occasion continued over the course of several episodes, those episodes are called *parts* (as with novels).

Serialized radio dramas are broadcast in *installments*, or sometimes *chapters*, *parts*, or *episodes*.

Serialized journalism is published in *parts*, as with novels.

Comment: The parts of Dickens' 19th century novels each contained several chapters. So I don't think *chapters* is the right term for the parts of 19th century novels.

Comment: @PeterShor, Re "*the  right term*": Already noted in 2nd paragraph, just past the 2nd comma.

Comment: That's not really *"the right term"* either. Dickens and his contemporaries called them *numbers*.

Comment: I'm not sure what term is most used for modern year-round weekday TV soap operas.

Comment: @PeterShor, Interesting, but did readers call them *numbers* too, or was that more a term of authorial shop-talk?  Anyway the Q. is more about current/latest usage, not so much prior contemporary usage.